# ListView listSelector

Tags: android

I am creating an android app which is having a listview.

Everything is working fine but when i click on any element of list-view ORANGE shade appears..
in order to remove that i wrote

```
     <ListView
    android:id="@+id/appslist"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
    android:listSelector="#424242"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corn2"
    android:padding="4dp"   
     >
```

In my list-view XML, but the problem with this is it remain highlighted until i click on any other time of that list or anywhere else..

I want a blink, How can i achieve this?

Comment: have you tried android:cacheColorHint="#0000", i've had this issue, but i usually fix it with my own Custom Adapter, although for you it might do the trick...

Comment: @MartinCazares : Sir android:cacheColorHint="#0000" is not even changing the colour from orange...

Comment: So, you want the list item's color to change to "#424242" and then change to white(or whatever color the item was before the click)?

Comment: Yes vikram.. how can i do it?